# How to zoom camera using Android CameraX API?

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, zooming, android-camerax

I have tried to zoom camera with below code using `CameraX`.

First I get a `Preview` from `CameraX` and tried to perform zoom using `Preview` like below.

```
var config = CameraX.getDefaultUseCaseConfig(PreviewConfig::class.java, lensFacing)
var preview = Preview(config)
preview.zoom(zoom)
```

After `preview.zoom()` I just bind again with `CameraX` and get some error and it's not working.

```
CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture, videoCapture)
```

When the above code was not working, I tried with `CameraX.unbindAll()` first and then I call `CameraX.bindToLifecycle()`. But face some error again and not get success in zoom.

**Let me know how we can zoom the camera using `CameraX` API.**

> **Update error log below:**

**Error log using only `CameraX.bindToLifecycle()`:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exceeded max simultaneously bound image capture use cases.
   at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.UseCaseSurfaceOccupancyManager.checkUseCaseLimitNotExceeded(UseCaseSurfaceOccupancyManager.java:61)
   at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.getSuggestedResolutions(Camera2DeviceSurfaceManager.java:146)
   at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.calculateSuggestedResolutions(CameraX.java:449)
   at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.bindToLifecycle(CameraX.java:144)
   at com.android.example.cameraxbasic.fragments.CameraFragment$updateCameraUi$2.onTouch(CameraFragment.kt:408)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:12512)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3032)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2719)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:475)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1836)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3404)
   at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:433)
   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12755)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5150)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4953)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4470)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4523)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4489)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4629)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4497)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4686)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4470)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4523)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4489)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4497)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4470)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7192)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7126)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7087)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7295)
   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:193)
   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:184)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:7266)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7318)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:690)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
```

**Error log using `CameraX.unbindAll()` and `CameraX.bindToLifecycle()`:**

```
   E/Legacy-CameraDevice-JNI: getNativeWindow: Surface had no valid native window.
   E/Legacy-CameraDevice-JNI: LegacyCameraDevice_nativeDetectSurfaceDimens: Could not retrieve native window from surface.

--------- beginning of crash
   2019-05-09 16:49:29.155 31123-31144/com.android.example.cameraxbasic E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraX-
Process: com.android.example.cameraxbasic, PID: 31123
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Surface was abandoned
    at android.hardware.camera2.utils.SurfaceUtils.getSurfaceSize(SurfaceUtils.java:84)
    at android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.<init>(OutputConfiguration.java:260)
    at android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.<init>(OutputConfiguration.java:145)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:518)
    at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.CaptureSession.open(CaptureSession.java:196)
    at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera.openCaptureSession(Camera.java:535)
    at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera$StateCallback.onOpened(Camera.java:743)
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraDeviceStateCallbacks$ComboDeviceStateCallback.onOpened(CameraDeviceStateCallbacks.java:99)
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:152)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
 Caused by: android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyExceptionUtils$BufferQueueAbandonedException
    at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyExceptionUtils.throwOnError(LegacyExceptionUtils.java:73)
    at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.getSurfaceSize(LegacyCameraDevice.java:606)
    at android.hardware.camera2.utils.SurfaceUtils.getSurfaceSize(SurfaceUtils.java:82)
    at android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.<init>(OutputConfiguration.java:260) 
    at android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.<init>(OutputConfiguration.java:145) 
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:518) 
    at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.CaptureSession.open(CaptureSession.java:196) 
    at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera.openCaptureSession(Camera.java:535) 
    at androidx.camera.camera2.impl.Camera$StateCallback.onOpened(Camera.java:743) 
    at androidx.camera.core.CameraDeviceStateCallbacks$ComboDeviceStateCallback.onOpened(CameraDeviceStateCallbacks.java:99) 
    at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:152) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) 


--------- beginning of system
```

Comment: @tynn Please check updated question I have added error log.

Comment: I think both approaches are wrong. You need to call `unbindAll()`, because you call `bindToLifecycle()` often. But that cleans up the use cases. Reusing these might not work well (yet). Have you tried calling `preview.zoom()` without rebinding anything?

Comment: @tynn, I have tried `preview.zoom()` without rebinding but nothing happens.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally, we get the Zoom API in CameraX. Please check below two way which you can use to zoom the preview of camera.

> **Pinch to zoom:**

```
val scaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(context, listener)

cameraTextureView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    return@setOnTouchListener true
}

val listener = object : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
    override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
        val scale = cameraInfo.zoomRatio.value * detector.scaleFactor
        cameraControl.setZoomRatio(scale)
        return true
    }
}
```

> **Slide to zoom(using seekbar):**

```
zoomSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {        
    override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
        cameraControl.setLinearZoom(progress / 100.toFloat())
    }

    override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}

    override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
})
```

**Use below to get `cameraControl`:**

```
val cameraControl = CameraX.getCameraControl(lensFacing)
```

> **Code reference link:**
>   https://github.com/Pinkal7600/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic

Comment: @SuyogDorlikar, Please check my edited google code sample which is working for zoom. I added the code sample link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: thanks! but only -" progress / 10.toFloat() "

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did on the latest CameraX 1.0.0-beta01 sample project. Added to bottom of onViewCreated

```
val listener = object : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
    val scale = camera!!.cameraInfo.zoomState.value!!.zoomRatio * detector.scaleFactor
        camera!!.cameraControl.setZoomRatio(scale)
        return true
    }
}

val scaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(context, listener)

viewFinder.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    return@setOnTouchListener true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For zoom to work properly, you also need to call zoom() *after* bindToLifecycle(). 
Also note that zoom() accepts a Rect which is in sensor coordinate. see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#SCALER_CROP_REGION) for more details.

You may also need to use camera2 API to get the [sensor active array](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE) and get the camera id (please use the first camera id that has the correct LENS_FACING). 
We know these are a lot of works so we are developing a new higher level zoom API that is much easier and simpler to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried zoom() after bindToLifecycle() with passing Rect in zoom method but didn't get any output. But Still, I will try with Camera2 API as you mention. Hope I'll get any output with camera zoom.

Comment: As you told you are developing new level zoom API which will be simple and easy. So, It will be different then what we work for zoom currently with the camera and camera2 API?

Comment: Yes,  the new zoom API will be different from camera1 and camera2 API.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. We are waiting for that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is unrelated to preview zoom:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exceeded max simultaneously bound image capture use cases.`

This indicates that you are calling `CameraX.bindToLifecycle(imageCapture)` more than once before unbinding it, and that is what is causing the crash. I would also recommend using the configuration builders instead of `getDefaultUseCaseConfig`, since they are more explicit and easier to read and `getDefaultUseCaseConfig` is a hidden API.

Please refer to the [official sample](https://github.com/android/camera/tree/master/CameraXBasic) for an example implementation and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't help me because I have done this zoom code by my own with help of official sample code from GitHub and there is no any kind of documentation where they mention about camera zoom using CameraX. Please let me know how to zoom? if you have any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener listener = new ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {
                ZoomState f = cam1.getCameraInfo().getZoomState().getValue();
                Log.d("Zoom", String.valueOf(f.getZoomRatio()));

                float scale = scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
                cam1.getCameraControl().setZoomRatio(scale * f.getZoomRatio());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {

            }
        };
        ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), listener);

        previewView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 1-create the object of "ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener" , it will listen to the screen touching/pinching. 2- make a object of ScaleGestureDetector 3- then set touch listener on preview "scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);"

Answer (score -1):

I am able to do zoom in/out using this code

```
val my = Rect(left, top, right, bottom)
preview.zoom(my)
```

see full-example on [github](https://github.com/Akshayrraiyani/CameraX_Zoom_In_Out) and just check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58023123/7719064)

It's perfectly working for me.